# A* complexities

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, a-star, space-complexity

I have implemented an A* algorithm which makes use of min priority queue. Now the implementation is very similar to the uniform-cost search which has time complexity of O(mlogn) and space complexity O(n^2) - since it keeps track of the parents and the nodes traversed using A*. Doesn't the time and space complexity for A* remain the same? Because in all the explanations that I am finding, the time and space complexity of A* is O(b^n)

Comment: I think your title can be better, see [ask]. Also you use the tag `dijkstra` but in the question you mention A* and not Dijkstra, you should probably use the `a-star` tag instead.

Comment: Do you mean A* using only uniform costs?